# Bluetooth not finding any devices on 12.10

Tags: drivers, 12.10, bluetooth

When I switch on my bluetooth and search for devices my laptop doesn't find any even though there's plenty in the area.

Most likely this is because of drivers that are missing. So what I want to know is if there's a way I can view the exact details of what bluetooth device I have built into my laptop so I can start searching for a linux version of the needed driver.

Any tips?

PS - Running 64bit 12.10

Comment: Make sure that your device (which that you want to connect with laptop) bluetooth mode is visible(not hidden).

Comment: @K.K Patel - It most certainly is visible. It's a Microsoft Notebook 5000 Mouse. Besides that fact it's not picking up ANY devices in the area.

Comment: Try putting your devices in *pairing* mode.

Comment: @Takkat - You're kidding me right?

Comment: Posted as a copy of a non-answer from user [Nick](http://askubuntu.com/users/107528/nick):
I seem to be having the same problem: [12.10 Bluetooth not detecting Wii remote](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244878/12-10-bluetooth-not-detecting-wii-remote) explains the issue I am seeing. Is `hcitool dev` returning a device for you?

Comment: please upgrade to 14.04 or 12.04 as these are LTS and currently supported versions as 12.10 ended it's life on 16 MAY 2014 you will always get obsolete or no drivers or a fetching error

Answer (score 0):

Type `Additional Drivers` in dash. Open it. It will check for drivers automatically and suggest for installing driver if found any.

Comment: Jockey does not come packaged with 12.10, Additional drivers can now be found as a tab in software sources.